# About the surname Yos(h)ida

Tags: translation, pronunciation, rōmaji, pitch-accent

I have recently bumped into the Japanese mathematician [吉田{よしだ}耕筰{こうさく}](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C5%8Dsaku_Yosida). I was wondering two things about his surname:

1. Why is it so often spelt *Yosida* instead of *Yoshida*? And taking lead from it, when did し change sound from /si/ to /ɕi/? That is, is it possible that at the time this mathematician was working his name was actually read /Josida/, hence the spelling? Or is it an older scheme of transliteration that stuck for some reason?
2. Where should I stress Yoshida? /'joɕida/, /jo'ɕida/ or /joɕi'da/? Naturally, the answer to this lies in the Japanese pitch accent, so how is the pitch accent of this particular word?

Comment: し is si in the nihonshiki romaji (日本式ローマ字) which tries to keep the romanization of the hiragana table regular, hence why it also maps つ to tu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Spelling conventions are different. It's almost certainly not the case that the pronunciation has changed since then, as evidence suggests that /si/ has been [ɕi] since Old Japanese in the 700s (and also suggests that /se/ was once [ɕe], meaning that the overall direction might well be from [ɕ] to [s] rather than the other way around). Some romanisation systems (such as Hepburn) prefer to represent as accurate a pronunciation as can be conveyed in letters (hence ‹shi›); other systems prefer either internal regularity or 1:1 phoneme-to-letter correspondences (giving ‹si› to be consistent with ‹sa› etc). These days the most common system for names is some variant of Hepburn; this was not always the case in the past (which is likely why your mathematician's name isn't in proper Hepburn).
2. As for the accent, my (admittedly non-native) gut instinct suggests [jòɕídá] or [jòɕídà] and [kóòsàkù]. Others can correct me.

Answer (score 1):

There is no  /si/ in Japanese.  /ɕi/ is the valid reading of し

し is romanized as SI and SHI, but it is always pronounced SHI (ɕi).

2. The stress I think comes naturally on the YO.  YOsheeda. KOosaku.

Comment: That is such a non-standard way of pronouncing 吉田.

Comment: would you stress the Shi?

Comment: @sova 普通は「[よしだ]{LHH}」「[こうさく]{LHHH}」「[よしだこうさく]{LHHHHHH}」って感じになると思います。